# PHP client side vs server side

Tags: php, security

I am currently working with PHP, just a beginner, but mainly interested in security issues regarding PHP. What I was wondering is "what does a client gets to see from the PHP files from a server".

So say for instance you have 1 sheet containing all your PHP code. You include the file and you call the function you want to use. What does the client sees from the sheet. Is it only the called function, just the output or something else?

The reason why I am interested is because I am wondering if a client could have the possibility to see what is truly being executed. So not only the outcome but also the content from the function itself, e.g. code being executed.

To put a vaguely story together. I am interested in how much you get to see as a client towards the server.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am sorry If I am posting a duplicate question. But I couldn't find anything similar to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the PHP is serverside nothing should be exposed to the client from the internal workings. Only the output (unless your server is wrongly configured and doesn't parse PHP files). To counter even this problem most people will just have an `index.php` file in their document root which `include`s a PHP file (bootstrap file) outside of the document root. This way even when the files aren't parsed by PHP the only thing accessible will be the file with `require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';` in it.

However it might be possible to leak information when you have enabled [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (which you should always do) *and* you have enabled [display errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

An example of leaking infromation *might* look like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Eeeeeeeek' in /path/to/Template/stream/stream.phtml:20 Stack trace: #0 /path/to/PitchBlade/src/PitchBlade/Mvc/View/View.php(179): require() #1 /path/to/PitchBlade/src/PitchBlade/Mvc/View/View.php(196): PitchBlade/Mvc/View/View->render('stream/stream.p...')
>
> /path/to/View/Stream/Stream.php(46): PitchBlade/Mvc/View/View->renderPage('stream/stream.p...')

*etc*

You can find out for youself by "faking" an exception somewhere deep in your code:

```
<?php throw new \Exception('Eeeeeeeek'); ?>
```

If the entire stack trace will be displayed there is lots of information exposed.

Another common pitfall is renaming PHP files (for the purpose of backup or whatever) by changing the extension. E.g. rename `index.php` to `index.php.bak`. Now by default PHP doesn't parse the file anymore and it could be read from the client side as is.

Also note that (some?) webservers expose some information to the client (i.e. webserver type and sometimes version and php version used). Depending on the webserver this can be changed by the [`expose_php` directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php) and by the directive for you used webserver. For apache you would add the following to the server config to prevent exposure of the webserver used (`ServerTokens Prod` and `ServerSignature Off`). Although people will often still be able to get at least some of this information by using a [fingerprinting technique](https://w3dt.net/tools/httprecon/).

One last thing I can think of is users (or possible attackers) trying out the different PHP "easter eggs" by appending one of the following query strings:

```
?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
?=PHPE9568F35-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000
?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
```

But IIRC this is also not possible when disabled `php_expose`.

Comment: So by just putting your PHP files outside your root you deny people, by restricting rights, from seeing/reaching the files. Is this the same method you use for storing DB connection information?

Comment: @KiptScriddy yes. Even inside the doc root it shouldn't be possible to read the file, but outside the chance of that when the server screwed up is a lot smaller.

Comment: More information about the [PHP 'easter eggs'](http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php)

Comment: I am abit confused about the easter eggs part. Isn't the idea that you could invoke an action, showing an elephant, but adding a query string? Why is this harmful for a site. It doesn't show any crucial information, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: It exposes the fact that the site runs on PHP and that itself is valuable information to the cracker. See http://www.ethicalhack3r.co.uk/full-path-disclosure-fpd/.

Comment: If you see that easter egg coming up you can be pretty sure PHP is running on the server. And what version of PHP is running depending on for example what logo is displayed. It isn't directly a security issue, but it is extra information for a possible attacker to find a possible attack surface.

Comment: Ahh I get it. It does indeed supply you with the needed information. Didn't see that the easter eggs showed a different image for each version.

Comment: Say for instance I want to black list the users requesting this query string, give a temporary IP ban of an hour or so, what is the best way for achieving this. It could either be done by checking the apache files or actively checking the request made by using a PHP function. But what is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

In normal circumstances, php code cannot be watched by a client. You can test this in eg chrome by right click on webpage and 'inspect element'.
The client can see cookies that you can set with php-code. To make sure it will not be used for the wrong purposes, you can use hash-functions to encrypt information that you've set with cookies.

example:

```
$pass = hash("ripemd160",$pass);
setcookie('password',"$pass",time()+3600);
```

Hope it helped!

PS: hash-functions aren't truly reliable, because there are ways too decrypt them. Althought this wouldn't be a good way to secure passwords (as PeeHaa said), it would be considerable for emailadresses.

Comment: No. Never ever store passwords in whatever form in a cookie.

Comment: It was just an example, i never set passwords as cookies ;) I'd rather do it with emailadresses